# Transform a List into a Page and sort it asc/desc

Tags: java, spring-boot

Hi everyone as the title suggests I should first turn a List into a Page and then sort this page by a certain item in the list, what can I do? "id" would be the element of the extendedResult list to be sorted asc or desc in my new Page. I write the code below:

```
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, pageSize, Sort.by("id").descending());
Page<ExtendedUserObject> extendedPageResult = new PageImpl<ExtendedUserObject> (extendedResult.subList(page, pageSize), pageable, extendedResult.size());
extendedUserObjectAndCount.setExtendedUserObjects(extendedPageResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

surpose 'id' is Integer type, and ExtendedUserObject has 'getId' method.

```
int start = page * pageSize;
boolean asc = ...
List<ExtendedUserObject> pagedList = extendedResult.stream()
                .sorted(object -> {
                   if(asc){
                      return Comparator.comparingInt(ExtendedUserObject::getId)
                   }
                   Comparator.comparingInt(ExtendedUserObject::getId).reversed()
                })
                .skip(start)
                .limit(pageSize)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Yes, your assumptions are correct, should the code you write me replace something of mine?

Comment: ok,the above code only sorted in asc.desc sorting should add some code.